# Download the content of a url and save it

Tags: python

I have this format of data from a url

```
 [{"column1":"something","column2":"something 2","column1":"something3","column2":"something4"}, etc]
```

I want to download this content from the url and save it into a csv file in this format:

```
 column1     column2

something   something2

something3  something4
```

Can I do it with python using urllib2? Or any other library?

Comment: I'm not sure how to load json, when there are multiple keys with the same value, it will get overwritten by last value

Comment: use `import json` and `json.load` and upvote and accept answers!

Answer (score 0):

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is probably the easiest for the download. You'd just use:

```
import codecs, requests

req = requests.get(url)
text = req.text.encode(req.encoding)
with codecs.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

As yedpodtrzitko mentioned, however, parsing that particular input as JSON will leave you with two key/value pairs, and it'll get overwritten with the last ones it encounters for each key. You could split and parse it manually into rows, but it shouldn't be valid JSON.